# How to get information of a data column by its id in Vuejs 2 using axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a job overview page like this:

**jobs.vue**

```
<div class="job-item" v-for="(item, index) in showJobs" :key="index">
          <a href=""
            ><h3 class="mleft-27">{{ item.position }}</h3></a
          >
                <img src="../assets/recruit/years.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.exprerience }}</b>
                <img src="../assets/recruit/luong.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.salary }}</b>
                <img src="../assets/recruit/diadiem.svg" alt="" />
                <b>{{ item.headequarters }}</b>
              <h6>{{ item.createdAt }}</h6>
            <div class="list-info-job">
              <ul>
                <li>{{ item.content1 }}</li>
                <li>{{ item.content2 }}</li>
                <li>{{ item.content3 }}</li>
              </ul>
            <a href="/detail">
              <button class="btn-detail">See Detail</button>
            </a>
          </div>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export defaul{
methods: {
    async getJobs() {
      await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:1337/jobinfos`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.jobinfos = response.data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
    },
}
</script>
```

I want when user click on **see details** button it will go to jobdetail.vue website and get data by id of given data column in jobs.vue
This is my jobdetail site overview:

**jobdetail:**

```
<div class="info-detail" v-for="(item, index) in jobinfos" :key="index">
            <div>
              <h6>Job Requirements</h6>
              <ul v-html="item.requirements">
                 
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-detail">
            <div>
              <h6>Skills</h6>
              <ul v-html="item.skills"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="info-detail">
            <div>
              <h6>Interests</h6>
              <ul v-html="item.interests"></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export defaul{
methods: {
    async getJobs() {
      await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:1337/jobinfos`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.jobinfos = response.data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
    },
}
</script>
```

Hope to receive help from everyone, thanks for taking some time to read the article! ^^

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should format your code for better looking.

As you are doing, here is my solution:

Modify this

```
<a href="/detail">
  <button class="btn-detail">See Detail</button>
</a>
```

Into some thing like this

```
<a :href="`/detail${item.id, item.key // or any property you want}`">
  <button class="btn-detail">See Detail</button>
</a>
```

This will redirect you to 'jobdetail' with the information you want in the url for getting data

Then in 'jobdetail' component you can use the information on url to get data

Comment: Chào bác ._. I tried <a :href="`/detail${item.id}`"> but the url I look up for a string is: http://localhost:8080/detailundefined, hope you can comment more...

Comment: It shoule be <a :href="`/detail${item.id}`"> you missing `` (string interpolation)

Comment: There is ` ` (string interpolation) but the query string above the URL still does not return the correct result....

Comment: Try to render out 'item' in your v-for, make sure item.id is exist

Comment: I solved the id problem, so what do I need to do on the details page now? thank you bro

Comment: Now you can get 'jobinfos' with the id on the url

Comment: Do you have a demo for the details page that I can refer to? thank you